# Enable only needed Reshaprer features

Tags: resharper

I used Resharper for a long time, but I removed it a while ago, because I hit the level where it become more of a distraction that lowers my productivity. I don't need it to hold my hand anymore and I really like my Visual Sudio as lean as possible.
However from time to time I encounter problems where I could make a very good use of a feature or two from it.

Is there a way to install Resharper, without it actually having an effect on anything and when the need arises for a specific feature I enable it one by one?

Comment: What features are you talking about? And what exactly made it distracting and lowering productivity? ReSharper can be configured to be almost invisible :)

Comment: Yes, almost invisibility would be a better way to put what I want. Distractions: all comes from the one size fits for all nature of the alike softwares. Working on opensource project where you are only supposed to edit what have to be done and resharper's constant complaining is a distraction. Slower VS is a distraction and other small things.

Comment: I guess by _distraction_ you mean warnings and suggestions. They can be turned off per solution. Regarding slowing down, you could have a look at the [Speeding up ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html) walkthrough.

Comment: I feel your pain. for me its the IDE gets very jittery and my machine is more than adequate to handle dev work. Its all the file processing and extra menu stuff it adds allover the place it really annoys me. Can I just turn the Test Runner on? Everything else to me is a distraction too